# implement custom multiple checkbox in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I want to achieve this, can anyone help me with this?
[image]

Comment: Kindly add some code which you have tried till now and share problem where you stuck

Comment: This is called the chip in Android, which is available by default. You can follow this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-p-chips-chipgroup

Answer (score 0):

This views are known as chips.
check out material3 chips.
[THIS LINK](https://m3.material.io/components/chips/overview)